# Rest DELETE API not working through code but working fine with postman/ swagger

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api

I am facing a strange issue where I have created a DELETE Rest API which is working from swagger / Postman but when trying through code it is not. I am getting getting the proper status code (200) back and the response body as well while trying through code. It means the API is executing fine but somehow it is not deleting data. The logic of delete API is just to clear a dictionary (This is a mock service). Below is the code I have written,

```
        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url); //I don't have any parameters to pass with the url
        httpWebRequest.Method = "DELETE";
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";

        using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse())
        using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            return(reader.ReadToEnd(),response.StatusCode);
        }
```

Comment: What do you pass as `url`? Do you pass parameters in the requestbody in postman? If so, it is missing in your code snippet.

Comment: I don't have any parameters to pass to the delete api

Comment: are you calling the right url?

Comment: @NielsNet yes I am. As I have mentioned I am getting proper HttpStatus code and the body I have configured in the delete api

Comment: then the problem must be in the api code.

Comment: @NielsNet if the problem is with api code then I am wondering how it is working with postman/swagger

Comment: That is why we need to see the api...

Answer (score 0):

There is one possibility is that there is a difference in the url which you are using in POSTMAN and the one you are using in code.If your delete method is executing and is returning the response as 200 then it means that your delete method is successfully returning values.But there is problem in what you are deleting ,such as the id used in deleting record.For example if you are using any repository for deleting the entity then you need to check that what is getting passed there.

You can set breakpoint in your code to check which id you are using while calling deleting from code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        var httpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(url);
        httpWebRequest.Method = "DELETE";
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";

        using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse())
        using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            return (reader.ReadToEnd(), response.StatusCode);
        }
```